# DashO: javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier not found

Tags: java, ssl, war, obfuscation, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on obfuscation of a war with **DashO 6.10.1** and during that process I am hitting with below error while running **obfuscate.xml**.

**Error:** com.preemptive.dasho.DashOClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier; super interface of com.abc.xyz.client.AbstractRestClient$1

and **warning:** Super interface of com.abc.xyz.client.AbstractRestClient$1 javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier not found

HttpClient contains javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier and this jar is included inside classpath section in the dox file.

I have below code because of which I had to import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier class.

```
final String hostname = "hostname";
if (hostname != null) {
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build(), new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return hostname.equals(arg0);
        }
    });
    clientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
}
```

**Below are my configurations:**

Java 1.6

DashO 6.10.1

HttpClient 4.5.2

Can someone please help me out of this issue?

Comment: Looks like DashO is not reading the javax package fully (Hence error: javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier not being found). Is RT.jar in your supporting classpath? I know there's the "Append current java runtime" setting in DashO but you could try unchecking it and manually adding the RT.jar.

Comment: Thanks @DankVader. I will try this. Can you give me a favor which obfuscator should I use? I am struggling with DashO.

Comment: DashO is up to version 7.10 as of this writing - 6.10.1 is almost 5 years old. Older versions won’t have the latest obfuscation techniques nor support for the latest Java versions and frameworks. If you still have an active contract, you should be able to upgrade for free. (https://www.preemptive.com/support/dasho-support/dasho-change-log)

Comment: Pretty much what Matt said. I've only had experience with the trial version, but it functions pretty well and is by far the most easy to use obfuscator out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding "${jsse.jar}" (without the quotes) to the support classpath in your project's configuration.  This can be found under Input->Support in the DashO UI.  If that does not work, manually add the path to jsse.jar located with your Java installation.